# An exercise from Fulton related to localization.

Tags: commutative-algebra, problem-solving, algebraic-curves, localization

Need a little help with the following problem.This problem appears in Fulton's book on algebraic curves.The question is as follows:

> Let $p=(0,0,...,0)\in \mathbb A^n$ and $\mathcal O_p=\mathcal O_p(\mathbb A^n)=\{f/g\in k(\mathbb A^n):g(p)\neq 0\}$ and $\mathbb m_p=\mathbb m_p(\mathbb A^n)=\{f\in \mathcal O_p:f(p)=0\}$ where $A()$ denotes the coordinate ring and $k()$ denotes the field of rational functions.Now suppose $I=\langle X_1,X_2,...,X_n\rangle\subset K[X_1,...,X_n]$,then $I\mathcal O_p=\mathbb m_p$.

My solution is as follows:

It is obvious that $\mathbb m_p\subset I\mathcal O_p$ because if $f\in \mathbb m_p$ then $f(p)=0$ and so $f\in I=\langle X_1,...,X_n\rangle$ and $1\in \mathcal O_p$ and hence $f\in I\mathcal O_p$.For the other way,let us take a general element from $I\mathcal O_p$ which looks like $f.\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$ where $\beta(p)\neq 0$ and $f(p)=0$ as $f\in I$ and thus $(f.\frac{\alpha}{\beta})(p)=0$ which gives us that the element is in $\mathbb m_p$.

I also think that it is quite obvious because $I$ is basically all the functions that vanish at $0$ and we are looking at the ideal generated by $I$ in the localization ring $\mathcal O_p$,so it should be nothing but $\mathbb m_p$ ,i.e. all the rational functions that vanish at $0$.

I am confused about the thing that $\mathbb m_p$ should be an ideal of $A(\mathbb A^n)$ but here the same $\mathbb m_p$ denotes an ideal in $\mathcal O_p$.

I am not sure whether I am making some mistake.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I assume that $p=0$? Otherwise its false, because if $p\neq 0$ then $f\in I$ doesn't imply $f(p)=0$ (you would have to take $I=\langle X_1-p_1,\ldots,X_n-p_n\rangle$). Other than that everything is fine! And yes sometimes there is a slight ambiguity about considering the maximal ideal in the coordinate ring or in the local ring, but they correspond in the way you are proving, so this slight abuse of notation often doesn't hurt.

Comment: @imtrying46 I have written in the question that $p=0$.

Comment: @imtrying46 It is already written there.

Comment: Ah yes I'm terribly sorry. In that case everything is fine!